# How can I split a string into groups?

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I'm trying to work out how to split a string into groups. I don't think the `split(regex)` method will suffice on it's own.

I have `String complexStatement = "(this && that)||(these&&those)||(me&&you)";` and I would like an array out with this kind of form:

```
"(this && that)","(these&&those)","(me&&you)""
```

If I had `"(5+3)*(2+5)+(9)"` then I'd like to have "(5+3)","(2+5)","(9)".
<sub>(bonus points if you can somehow keep the *join* information, e.g. `*,+,||`)</sub>

Is this possible for an arbitrary string input? I'm playing with a StringTokenizer but I haven't quite gotten to grips with it yet.

Comment: You want to keep only those things enclosed in parentheses?  What about nested parentheses?  What about unbalanced parentheses?

Comment: @RayToal I'm not sure. I think if I can split on just outside parentheses I can loop inward on each eventually? or is that naive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the bellow code:

```
    String str = "(this && that)\",\"(these&&those)\",\"(me&&you)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\)]+)\\)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

`\\(([^\\)]+)\\)` will dig you anything within the parenthesis, look like what you want!:

***Edit:***

To capture content between `)` and `(` just replace the regular expression with `\\)([^\\(]+)\\(` this one!

Comment: This is great! I'm trying to make a regex to match anything between `)(` so it'd pick up `),(` and `)&&(`. I've tried `"(?:\\(.*\\)(.+)\\(.*\\))?"` but to no avail. Where am I slipping up? Also, it appears to match the start and end of <b>(</b>1),(2),(3<b>)</b>, why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you better implement the parsing instead of depending on any ready-made methods.

Here is my suggestion... I am assuming the format of input will be always like followig

```
(value1+operator+value2)+operator+(value3+operator+value4)+........
```

[here operator can be different, and + is just showing concatanation).

If the above assumptio is true then you can do the following.

1. Use a stack
2. While reading the original string push all the characters into the stack
3. now popup one by one from the stack by using following logic
   a. if get ) start adding to a string
   b. if get ( add to the string and now you get one token. add the token to the array.
   c. after getting ( skip till the next ).

N.B. it's just and pseudo code with primitive thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the groups defined *only* by parentheses at the outermost level, you are outside of the world of regular expressions and will need to parse the input.  StinePike's approach is good; another one (in messy pseudocode) is as follows:

```
insides = []
outsides = []
nesting_level = 0
string = ""
while not done_reading_input():
    char = get_next_char()
    if nesting_level > 0 or char not in ['(', ')']:
        string += char
    if char == '('
        if nesting_level == 0:
            outsides.add(string)
            string = ""
        nesting_level += 1
    elif char == ')':
        nesting_level -= 1
        if nesting_level == 0:
            insides.add(string)
            string = ""
```

If the very first character in your input is a '(', you'll get an extra string in your `outsides` array, but you can fix that without much trouble.

If you are interested in *nested parentheses* then you will not be producing just two arrays as output; you will need a tree.